# event.preventDefault() - not working with loaded <a>

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

My code:

```
 $('.menu a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent().children('ul').is('.deep1')){
        var result = $(this).parent().children('ul').html();
        $('.dpp1').html('<ul class="menu" style="display: none">'+result+'</ul>');
        $('.dpp1').children('.menu').stop().fadeIn()
    }else if($(this).parent().children('ul').is('.deep2')){
        var result = $(this).parent().children('ul').html();
        $('.dpp2').html('<ul class="menu" style="display: none">'+result+'</ul>');
        $('.dpp2').children('.menu').stop().fadeIn()
    }else if($(this).parent().children('ul').is('.deep3')){
        var result = $(this).parent().children('ul').html();
        $('.dpp3').html('<ul class="menu" style="display: none">'+result+'</ul>');
        $('.dpp3').children('.menu').stop().fadeIn() 
    }
 });
```

My question is how to keep it working preventDefault() in created elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the anchors are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //........
});
```